# Liquid soaking into other objects?

Tags: modeling, effects, mantaflow

How would you go about making a liquid soak into another object? (or at least give the illusion).

Heres a link to the effect Im referring to.

https://gfycat.com/daringaltruisticdwarfmongoose

[image]

Comment: use force fields and/or curve guide

Comment: There is no simple solution to that in Blender. The flower part makes it incredibly hard. If you only need to do this for a mesh object, let me know, there's a solution using Dynamic Paint, but it won't work (well) on particles.

Comment: Yeah Im just trying to do this on a mesh object!